# Are smooth affine L-varieties the same as almost smooth affine L-varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-vector-bundles

Suppose I have a finite extension $K\subseteq L$ of perfect fields. To any smooth affine $L$-variety $V$ I can associate the Weil restriction $W=\mathrm{Res}_{L/K}(V)$, a smooth $K$-variety with an $L$-linear structure on the sheaf of differentials, compatible with the $K$-linear structure; that is, an extension of the action of $\mathcal{O}_W$ on $\Omega_{W/K}$ to $\mathcal{O}_W\otimes_K L$ such that the extension to $\overline{W}=W\otimes_K\overline{K}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_{\overline W}\otimes_K L$-module. Call a smooth variety equipped with such a structure a smooth almost-$L$ variety, in analogy with almost-complex manifolds. My questions are:

1. Is the Weil restriction functor from affine smooth $L$-varieties to affine smooth almost-$L$-varieties fully faithful?
2. Is it essentially surjective? I doubt it is.
3. If the answer to 2 is no, can we describe its essential image?

Of course, we can ask the same questions about locally analytic manifolds over complete DVRs or smooth rigid analytic spaces. I ask because the analogy of questions 1+2 came up for locally analytic manifolds over p-adic fields a few years ago and I still don't know a good answer.

Comment: Maybe a bit naive but won't you only get varieties of dimension dividing $[L:K]$? Alternatively is it known that this dimensionality condition is necessary for the existence of the almost-$L$ structure on a $K$-variety?

Comment: @Arkady This is a good point, which actually answers question 2. I assumed it did: any finite-dimensional K-vector space V with a compatible L-structure (that is, any L-vector space) automatically has K-dimension $[L:K]\mathrm{dim}_L(V)$. If the variety (is of pure dimension and) has a K-rational point, applying this to the cotangent space shows the dimension is divisible by $[L:K]$. What I didn't realize is this assumption is necessary: assuming separability(?), $\mathrm{Spec} L[x]$ has an almost-L structure but is of dimension 1, so it is not a Weil restriction unless $L=K$.

Comment: ......... I think this is just a defect in my question: the correct question should assume something be free over $L\otimes_K \overline{K}$ ..... or something like that. But tragically, it's too late to change the question.

Comment: @Arkady See now, the dimension should be automatic. Note I'm not 100% sure a Weil restriction is a smooth almost-L variety under this definition: I think I see how to show it, but I'm a little too tired to be certain right now.